# Allow file download `example.com\Folder1\File1.zip`, but prevent Folder1 listing?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

I'd like to have access to some files via web browser, but at the same time I'd like to prevent listing all files in the folder.

For example,

Allow file download `www.example.com/Folder1/File1.zip`

but don't allow folder listing `www.example.com/Folder1/`.

Using Apache web server.

Is this possible?

Comment: which web server? apache? nginx? iis? Can't you just put an empty index.html there, or disable directory index (in the config or via .htaccess)

Comment: Empty index.html is a good idea! Will try.

Comment: Done..........!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: I changed permissions on folder to prevent all acces (`chmod 700`), and at the same time I changed permissions on the File.zip to allow acces to file (`chmod 755`).